# Changing a value in an array of arrays seemingly changing corresponding value in next array

Tags: python, arrays

I was making a rudimentary Snake game and ran into this problem. I am completely dumbfounded as to why this is happening, here is the code.

self._body is as array of arrays as such:

```
[[15, 20], [16, 20], [17, 20]]
```

The goal of this code is to make that into:

```
[[14, 20], [15, 20], [16, 20]]
```

Seems simple right? Here is the problem code, note the position of the print statements:

```
        if move == 'w' or move == 'W' :
            print(self._body)
            for i in range(len(self._body)-1,0,-1):
                self._body[i] = self._body[i-1]
            print(self._body)
            self._body[0][0] -= 1
            print(self._body)
```

The output of this code is:

```
[[15, 20], [16, 20], [17, 20]]
[[15, 20], [15, 20], [16, 20]]
[[14, 20], [14, 20], [16, 20]]
```

It is all correct until the last statement.

for some reason,

```
 self._body[0][0] -= 1
```

changes both

```
self._body[0][0]
```

and

```
self._body[1][0]
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Even if I could work around I still really want to know why this happens.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
self._body[i] = self._body[i-1]
```

This will *not* make a copy of the right-hand list. It will assign the *exact same list object* to both variables. So if you change one, you change the other. You need to make a copy of the list instead, like so:

```
self._body[i] = list(self._body[i-1])
```

This trips up a lot of people. Just remember that you have to explicitly copy lists.

Comment: You can also do `self._body[i] = self._body[i-1][:]`

Comment: Ah. I thought that may have been the case and attempted to use temp variables, but I guess the objects will continue to be passed on and changed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The issue is even when you make a temp variable in Python, you are just creating a variable with the same pointer to the original instance.